# Count Triplets error on hackkerank

Tags: python, algorithm

[Link to count triplets problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/count-triplets-1/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps)

Below on the following code the hackerrank website says the answer is incorrect, however when I run the code on my local machine. Specifically test case 2, which is an array of 100 1s and has a triplet multiplier of 1, The expected output is supposed to be 161700, and on my local machine I get 161700, however on the hackerrank website I get that it is incorrect.

```
 def countTriplets(arr, r):
        sum_array=[]
        if int(r)==1:
            for x in range(len(arr)-1):
                sum_array.append((x*(x+1))/2)
            return sum(sum_array)
        else:
            exp_dict={}
            tripletCount=0
            for x in arr:

                if x in exp_dict:
                    exp_dict[x]+=1
                else:
                    exp_dict[x]=1
            for y in exp_dict:
                #print(y)

                if ((y % r ==0) or (y==1)) and ((y*r in exp_dict) and (y*r*r in exp_dict)):
                    #print((exp_dict[y]*exp_dict[y*r]*exp_dict[y*r*r]))
                    tripletCount+=(exp_dict[y]*exp_dict[y*r]*exp_dict[y*r*r])
                    #print("hello I am a computer nerd")


            return tripletCount
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

To pass online coding challenges your output format must match the expected format. Your program was producing `161700.0` and the expected answer was `161700`. This is happening because of the division. I converted the return value to `int` and it passed the case.

```
def countTriplets(arr, r):
    sum_array=[]
    if int(r)==1:
        for x in range(len(arr)-1):
            sum_array.append((x*(x+1))/2)
        return int(sum(sum_array))    # change in this line
    else:
        exp_dict={}
        tripletCount=0
        for x in arr:

            if x in exp_dict:
                exp_dict[x]+=1
            else:
                exp_dict[x]=1
        for y in exp_dict:
            #print(y)

            if ((y % r ==0) or (y==1)) and ((y*r in exp_dict) and (y*r*r in exp_dict)):
                #print((exp_dict[y]*exp_dict[y*r]*exp_dict[y*r*r]))
                tripletCount+=(exp_dict[y]*exp_dict[y*r]*exp_dict[y*r*r])
                #print("hello I am a computer nerd")

        return tripletCount
```

However it still doesn't solve 100% of the test cases. This answer is specific to the test case you asked.